# Export BinarySearchTree entries to List

Tags: java, list, data-structures

Note that the BinarySearchTree class is from net.datastructures 5.0

```
   public static <K, V extends Comparable> List<Entry<K, V>> sortTree(BinarySearchTree<K, V> tree) 
    {   
        List<Entry<K, V>> entries = new ArrayList<Entry<K, V>>(tree.size()); 
        entries.addAll(tree.entries());
```

How am I going to solve this problem ?

```
 Error: The method addAll(Collection<? extends Entry<K,V>>) in the type List<Entry<K,V>> is not applicable for the arguments (Iterable<Entry<K,V>>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Entry<K,V> entry : tree.entries()) { entries.add(entry);}
```